# Docker Volumes lost (and DDEV databases) during OS upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, drupal, ddev, drupal-9

About a month ago I created a Drupal 9 instance using DDEV. It was fast and easy! I spent about 8 hours over several user sessions on my Linux laptop customizing my content types and views.

Last week I upgraded my Pop! OS (Ubuntu-like) laptop, and had to re-install ddev after the upgrade. When I went back into my local directory and ran `ddev start`... I was greeted with a clean Drupal 9 installation screen. All of my configuration and content seems to be gone?

What steps are there to troubleshoot lost state information, such as a database or filesystem? Are there any chances of finding my previous changes inside the /.ddev/ folder somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently lost your Docker volumes (which is where the database is kept).  I'm sure there's a way to go back to your backups and find them (they were in /var/lib/docker/volumes), but the real point here is to keep database backups. Use `ddev snapshot` or `ddev export-db` from time to time and keep those backups around.

I keep a .tarballs directory in each project where I have a basic `ddev export-db` output and a files dump. It's worked well.

Note that you wouldn't have to reinstall DDEV after a normal OS upgrade, nor would you have to reinstall Docker. I imagine it's the reinstalling of Docker that got you in trouble.